# How get Category Id and Category Label

Tags: magento2, category

> I get product like this way, but how can I get sub category now and ids and label?

```
$objectManager = \Magento\Framework\App\ObjectManager::getInstance();
        $categoryFactory = $objectManager::getInstance()->get(\Magento\Catalog\Model\CategoryFactory::class);
        $productRepository = $objectManager->get('\Magento\Catalog\Model\ProductRepository');
        $resourceConection = $objectManager->get('\Magento\Framework\App\ResourceConnection');
        $eavConfig = $objectManager->get('\Magento\Eav\Model\Config');
        $jsonHelper = $objectManager->get('\Magento\Framework\Json\Helper\Data');

        $category = $categoryFactory->create();

        $products = $category->load($categoryId)->getProductCollection();


        $products->addAttributeToSelect('*');
        $products->addAttributeToFilter('product_type_custom', array('notnull' => true))->getSelect()->group('product_type_custom');

    $_optionText =  "";

    $firstArray = array();
        //echo $products->getSelect();
        foreach($products as $product)
{
}
```

Comment: i think you are going wrong way!!

Comment: actually i need product of specific cateogeory i load collection like that and got product collecion successfully now i want product category

Comment: where do you want to use it ? for a block ?

Comment: actually i am createing search so i need 4 attribute i got others but now i need cateogyr attribute alos

Answer (score 0):

Create a Block file : `app/code/YourCompanyName/YourModuleName/Block/YourCustomBlock.php`

```
<?php
namespace YourCompanyName\YourModuleName\Block;
class YourCustomBlock extends \Magento\Framework\View\Element\Template
{ 
    protected $_categoryCollectionFactory;

    protected $_categoryHelper;

    public function __construct(
        \Magento\Framework\View\Element\Template\Context $context,
        \Magento\Catalog\Model\ResourceModel\Category\CollectionFactory $categoryCollectionFactory,
        \Magento\Catalog\Helper\Category $categoryHelper,
        array $data = []
    ) {
        $this->_categoryCollectionFactory = $categoryCollectionFactory;
        $this->_categoryHelper = $categoryHelper;
        parent::__construct($context, $data);
    }

    public function getCategoryCollection($isActive = true, $level = false, $sortBy = false, $pageSize = false) {
        $collection = $this->_categoryCollectionFactory->create();
        $collection->addAttributeToSelect('*');

        // select only active categories
        if ($isActive) {
            $collection->addIsActiveFilter();
        }

        // select categories of certain level
        if ($level) {
            $collection->addLevelFilter($level);
        }

        // sort categories by some value
        if ($sortBy) {
            $collection->addOrderField($sortBy);
        }

        // set pagination
        if ($pageSize) {
            $collection->setPageSize($pageSize); 
        } 

        return $collection;
    }

    public function getStoreCategories($sorted = false, $asCollection = false, $toLoad = true) {
        return $this->_categoryHelper->getStoreCategories($sorted = false, $asCollection = false, $toLoad = true);
    }
}
```

Now, we can use the functions in our view (.phtml) file as follows.

```
// get the list of all categories
$categories = $block->getCategoryCollection(); 
foreach ($categories as $category) {
    echo $category->getId() . '<br />';
    echo $category->getName() . '<br />';
}

// get categories sorted by category name
$categories = $block->getCategoryCollection(true, false, 'name', false);
foreach ($categories as $category) { 
    echo $category->getId() . '<br />';
    echo $category->getName() . '<br />';
}

// get current store’s categories
$categories = $block->getStoreCategories();
foreach ($categories as $category) { 
    echo $category->getId() . '<br />';
    echo $category->getName() . '<br />';
}
```